# Create a link to add Matrix stored event to iCal using Easy iCal

Tags: expresso, ical

Sorry if this is obvious but we have an entry which contains multiple venues and dates for a specific event.

I want the user to be able to add a specific venue and date to iCal by simply clicking on a link.

The Easy iCal docs are a bit light so can someone explain the best way to do this.

PS. Using Stash if that makes it easier!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure whether the ical format supports multiple venues, but I'm pretty sure the easy_icalendar plugin doesn't. It was only designed for our specific requirements (a long time ago), so feel free to bend it to your needs.

To create multiple dates, you would simply create multiple events using a loop inside the calendar tag, as per the example:

```
{exp:easy_ical:calendar timezone="Pacific/Auckland" name="My Simple Event Calendar"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes" limit="20"}
        {exp:easy_ical:event uid="{entry_id}" start_time="{entry_date}" end_time="{expiration_date}" location="{event_location}" summary="{title}"}
            {event_description}
        {/exp:easy_ical:event}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:easy_ical:calendar}
```

Comment: I realise I wasn't being very clear!

I need to use a specific Matrix row but the plugin doesn't generate the specific code if I pass through more than 3 segments. E.g.

<a href="{path="ical/event/{entry_id}"}">

Comment: dynamic="no" Grrrrr all working now!

Comment: Hah. ALWAYS use `dynamic="no"`. `yes` should be the exception.